# strange backslash operator in C assignment

Tags: c, embedded, texas-instruments

What does following `0x0\1` mean in following code? I find this in an embedded C code:

```
uint16 size;
...
size += (size & 0x0\1);
```

It's part of Texas Instruments released code. It compiles in IAR ARM IDE.

Comment: I'm not able to get the code in question to compile.

Comment: It's part of TI released code. It compiles in IAR ARM IDE.

Comment: Probably just octal 1. But don't ask me why.

Comment: I'm not able to get it to compile, either (under gcc or clang).  gcc complains (and not surprisingly) about "stray ‘\’ in program".  This is not portable code.  The backslash there has no meaning in portable C.  Whatever it means, we can't tell you; you might have to ask TI.

Comment: Can you compile the code?  In that case, maybe you can see if there is a difference in the binary.  What if it was a misprint?  There is a texas-instruments tag too that might help.

Comment: @SteveSummit I think the hope is that someone with specific knowledge of the TI compiler will see the question. I'll admit the odds are against it.

Comment: I suggest using `printf("%d\n", 0x0\1);` to find out what it translates to (most likely, it is equivalent to `1`, but it's non-standard so anything is possible).  Then either edit the code to replace it, or ignore it for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-portable, implementation dependent, non-standard conforming code. 
It is anybody's guess what the original author has intended but "probably" means `size += size & 0x1`. That is: increment size by 1 in case size is odd (that is, least significant bit is 1).